# Why does Zootopia have an intentional Breaking Bad reference?

Tags: analysis, breaking-bad, reference, zootopia

When Judy is looking up on the case she finds, along with Nick, that there's *a laboratory in a vehicle* which processes *a blue chemical* to be sold in the market. While the chemist is making the preparation, he receives some other characters at his door so he interrupts his phone call explaining: "*Woolter and Jesse* are back, so I'm leaving now."

All the set up seems a general reference to the [Breaking Bad series](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0903747/) (2008-2013). Is there any important reason to make this reference. Just a cultural tribute or something else?

[image: Breaking bad easter egg]

Comment: I guess it's both cultural and important, since the Nighthowlers are some kind of drugs and it was an opportunity to bring the puns and references to the movie

Comment: Not to forget that "Woolter" alone is a great name for a ram.

Comment: @nilon They included [**a scene from the Godfather too**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJ-LWlmj3kQ). I think they wanted to give the adults their share from the movie. So both kids and their parents can have fun.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The directors addressed this scene and their motivation directly, indicating that it was both a cultural homage and just a really good joke:

> The gag works. During copious test screenings, Moore and Howard say they can consistently count on hearing adults crack up at the reference, coursing through the audience like a ripple the kids never notice.
>
> The duo continues, “We kept thinking, well, at some point we’ve got to
>   pull this back, but as we kept building the scene and designing it, we
>   kept saying, well, there’s nothing really offensive about this. It’s a
>   ram growing flowers in an abandoned train car, making a chemical
>   serum. It evokes a show from pop culture, but it’s not like it’s
>   something that’s offensive to the audience. But it really puts you
>   into that mindset.”

They have much more to say about this scene in the [*Entertainment Weekly* article](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/03/15/zootopia-breaking-bad) that the above quote comes from.

Comment: I found that scene to be the funniest one in the movie, I think, largely because of the cultural reference but also it was just really good regardless

Answer (score 3):

Kid's movies and TV often contain jokes/references or other Easter eggs that only adults will catch. This entertains the parents, while going over the kid's heads. For example in *Scooby Doo (2002)* Shaggy meets a girl and she says her name is Marry Jane to which he replies,  "That's my favorite name". Kids wouldn't understand that joke, but parents would. Similar to this movie, it's a reference to a TV show that mostly only parents would watch so only they would understand that joke, it's a harmless way to keep the parents entertained while watching a movie that might not be their first choice.

Comment: my kid found out about that, and I had to explain several of these parent jokes  ... :( Sometimes, I just lied.